# Net health monitoring

Tags: javascript, performance, datetime, node.js, matrix

This is a little net health monitoring project I made in NodeJS. It pings Google every second and stores the result (true/false) along with the date in a database (MongoDB). I've collected enough data and I want to represent it for the past week.

I created a 2x2 array of 7 days and 24 hours each. I go through each record and map it to the appropriate day and hour of the week. And I give that hour a little score: if true +1, if false -5. And it creates a little matrix like this:

```
[
    [2015, 1724, 1733, 1679, ...
    [1818, 1909, 1614, 1829, ...
    [1632, 1778, 1726, 1657, ...
    ...
]
```

The only problem is computation takes ~10-15 seconds and lots of CPU for going through ~200k records of just 3 days.

Is there some scope for improvement here?

```
days = days || 3;
var counter = 0
this.find({
    date: {
        // Date greater than (Now - X days)
        $gt: new Date(Date.now() - days * 24 * 3600 * 1000),
    },
}, function(err, datums) {
    var week = new Array(days);
    for (var i = 0; i < week.length; i++)
        week[i] = new Array(24);
    // Empty Week Matrix (7x24)
    datums.forEach(function(data) {
        counter++;
        var date1 = data.date;
        var date2 = new Date();
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        //stackoverflow.com/q/3224834/1266650

        var day = days - diffDays;
        if (day < 0) return;
        var hour = data.date.getHours();

        if (!week[day][hour]) week[day][hour] = 0;
        if (data.isNetAlive)
            week[day][hour]++;
        else
            week[day][hour] -= 5;
    });
    console.debug(week);
    console.debug(counter, 'records');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to move out `1000`, `3600`, `24` to "constants" so that they're properly described. Something like:

```
var HOURS_A_DAY = 24;
var MILLISECONDS_A_SECOND = 1000;
var SECONDS_AN_HOUR = 3600;
```

In addition, you can name your variables properly so that they're easily understood. `timeDiff` could be `timeDifference`, `diffDays` could be `daysDifference`.

Creating date objects per iteration is costly. Try operating using milliseconds instead. Make `data.date` return milliseconds for `date1`. Then use `Date.now()` on `date2`. Also, if possible, avoid doing `getTime()` and `getHours()`. Try calculating them manually.

Next, [`Math.abs` can be done using a bitwise operation](http://jsperf.com/math-abs-vs-bitwise/7). The same could be done for `Math.ceil`, just look around the internet. Here's an example of a bitwise `Math.abs`, where `n` is the number to absolutify.

```
return (n < 0) ? (~n + 1) : n
```

Bitwise isn't the solution to all math performance problems and highly depends on the JS engine running. Some bitwise operations are faster than their high-level counterparts, some the other way around. Highly depends on the combination, so try checking which ones work for you.

```
if (!week[day][hour]) week[day][hour] = 0;
```

Property access and condition evaluation can be costly. Move this out to the for-loop that builds your matrix. This has nothing to do with the data crunching. It's just initializing a hole in the array to `0`.

Lastly, for a more beautiful code, let's make everything less redundant and more consistent-looking.

```
week[day][hour] += data.isNetAlive ? 1 : -5;
```